# How do you not cache a img-src in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have an angular SPA with a form to manage image files on the backend. There is a file input to change the file and an img tag to show the current image.

The page starts with an img-src to the backend `/api/Media/123` showing the current contents, I then choose a file and this results in the img-src to become a blob URL to the local file showing that. I then PUT that new file to the backend to `/api/Media/123`, store it, and then change the img-src back to `/api/Media/123`. I'm not sure this is relevant, but I also have a service worker installed and this mangles the GET requests for images to add authorization using a bearer token (it's not touching the Cache API).

I now want the img element to show the updated file's contents by GET'ing it from the backend and I want this to work with proper HTTP cache headers instead of cache-busting URL manipulations.

I started with a server response that includes `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` and an ETag and Chromium works in that setup: When I navigate through the application, the image is revalidated, then for a smallish time window, revalidation doesn't happen during navigation, but as soon as I PUT the updated image, Chromium revalidates the image and downloads the updated version to show in the img tag.

In Firefox, though, I cannot get the updated file contents to show up in the img tag.
The initial GET request is shown as `Transferred` `service worker` and comes back with configured headers. Then the PUT is shown. But the follow-up GET request always shows `cached` in the Transferred column and the service worker does not see any fetch event.

I have tried a number of things today to get Firefox to do something sensible, but the above behavior just won't change. Amongst those were `Cache-Control: no-store, private` and `Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, private` and removing the ETag, I also experimented with a `Content-Location` header in the PUT request.

What is going on?